# How to get URL of parent window without javascript?

Tags: php

I have a HTML file *http://mydomain.com/page1.html*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <iframe src="http://mydomain.com/page2.php"></iframe>
</html>
```

In *page2.php*, I would like to get the url of the "container page", which in this case is the string `page1.html`.

Is there anyway to do so **without javascript**?

Comment: i am not sure it can be done but can you check you put print_r($_SERVER) array in page2.php and see what the answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser *may* send the parent's URL as Referer in the HTTP request, so look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. That's not guaranteed though. As such, there's no 100% foolproof way. If the client doesn't supply the information in the request, there's nothing else whatsoever you can do on the server side without explicitly passing the parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Why not pass some ununsed GET parameter to the inner page?

```
<iframe src="http://mydomain.com/page2.php?outerPageURL=<URL_ENCODED_CURRENT_URL>></iframe>
```

The inner page can then do:

```
$_GET['outerPageURL'];
```

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose.. the whole point is to do it without a *protocol* on top of it.

Comment: I do not understand your point. You want to do it without using JS, and using something like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can not be reliable. There's no harm using a parameter like that esp, when the inner page **must** know the URL of the outer page.

Comment: True that referer is not reliable. Thanks =) But what I meant was this solution is like pretty obvious, the solution that I was searching for is to do it without having to have a protocol on top of it.

Comment: @Pacerier Why make it easy if there may be a hard solution, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `$_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']` for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it will may not work sometimes. There's no other way as far as I know, without using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in PHP.

To get the URL in your case `base url`:

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```